# how to get the inverse of a log10 value in python?

Tags: python, inverse

```
y=np.log10(train_set["SalePrice"])
```

how do i find inverse of this ?? I want it to return back to the original value and not the scaled value

Comment: whats wrong with `10 ** y`? Actually, what's wrong with `train_set["SalePrice"]`?

Comment: On the face of it this is indeed a silly question because you still have the original data but I found it useful since I found it by googling Pyton Antilog.  Of course I know that alog10(y) = 10**(y) but its not as explicit/readable as the former so its a relevant question.

Comment: I don't see it as a silly question. I rather think that that user just missed the fact that the inverse of `log10` is just the classical power of 10. Everyone has his/her self easiness in maths...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have a look here for logarithm inversion: https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.html

`10 ** y` should do the trick for you here

Answer (score 19):

Hope the above answers were helpful, in case you or anyone want the inverse for log10 (base 10) and log (natural)

```
# Logarithm and back to normal value
y = np.log10(train_set["SalePrice"])
train_set["SalePrice"] = 10 ** y

# Natural log and back to normal value using built-in numpy exp() function
y = np.log(train_set["SalePrice"])
train_set["SalePrice"] = np.exp(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to obtain the original value then you can do:

```
z = 10**y
```

Answer (score 3):

y = np.log10(train_set["SalePrice"])

## return back to the original value all of array elements

```
Z = np.array(10**y)
```