# How to convert single pandas dataframe column from log values (log10) back to normal values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple pandas dataframe consisting of a date interval column and a column of values (RRP_SA) as depicted in the snippet below. They are stored in a pandas dataframe (df_forecast). How can I take the 'RRP_SA' column, convert the entire column from log10 to normal format (as it is currently in log10 format), and then add this as a new column to the 'df_forecast' dataframe.

[image: Pandas Dataframe layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to do this using the following command:

```
df_forecast["value"] = 10 ** df_forecast["RRP_SA"]
```

as it is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669437/8541242)